# Single line function call without for block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make a single line call to a function over an iterable in Python?

**Background:**

Suppose I wanted to create a single sub-directory in a list of directories. Traditionally I would use list comprehension to build a list of the desired sub-directory paths:

`subs = [os.path.join(root, "sub") for root in roots]`

Where `roots` is the list of directories. I would then have to create a `for` block to call `os.mkdir()`:

```
for sub in subs:
    os.mkdir(sub)
```

**Question:**

> *Is it possible to use generators to accomplish this?*

I've tried:
`os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, "sub") for root in roots)`

But it throws a `TypeError` saying a generator is not accepted.

Comment: You _could_ rewrite your loop as a list comprehension. But you shouldn't really. Because you're not trying to create a new list. You're trying to execute a command in a loop. That's what the normal `for` statement is for.

Comment: Single line: `for sub in subs: os.mkdir(sub)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That does not solve the problem. Before that can be executed `subs` would still need to be made, I am trying not to create another list object.

Comment: Then do: `for sub in (os.path.join(root, "sub") for root in roots): os.mkdir(sub)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
[os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, "sub")) for root in roots]
```

This works because the list comprehension will be executed even if you don't assign its result anywhere. The `os.mkdir` calls will return `None`, so the result will be a list of `None`s (which you don't need to care about), but the effect of the function will take place.

Now, it is debatable whether that or:

```
for root in roots:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, "sub"))
```

Or even:

```
for root in roots: os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, "sub"))
```

Is more readable, since people generally expect list comprehensions to generate lists and loops to perform actions, so it may be easy, for example, to miss that you are actually creating folders when you are reviewing the code if you do it inside of a comprehension. But if you *want*, you can.

Comment: I did not know I could use list comprehension for this. Good to know. While the `for` block is traditional, it just eliminates extra lines from the program to build lists followed by subsequent `for` loops for each list. Would rather the single liner with a view `#` comments to explain.

Comment: @datta If you're going to add comments for such simple stuff, then you're doing it wrong. The for-loop is much more obvious and doesn't require any explanation.

Comment: I really don't like list comprehensions written specifically to produce a side affect.  my two cents anyway.